# Contradiction of cublasDgetrfBatched and cublasDtrsmBatched when to solve array of linear systems using cuBLAS

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu, cublas

I have lots of dense linear systems which I want to solve in cuBLAS **Batched** format. So my plan is

1. use ***cublasDgetrfBatched*** for batched LU decomposition
2. Then use ***cublasDtrsmBatched***  for batched lower triangular and batched upper triangular part one by one.

The code is given as

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<cuda_runtime.h> 
 #include<device_launch_parameters.h>
 #include<cublas_v2.h>

 const int N = 32;
 const int Nmatrices = N;

 __global__ void initiate(double *d_A, double *d_B)
    {
     int i = threadIdx.x;       int j = blockIdx.x;

     int id = j*N*N + i*N;      int idb = j*N + i;  

     for(int k = 0; k< N ; k++)
         {
        d_A[id + k] = 0.0;

        if(k == i-2)    d_A[id + k] = 1.0; 
        if(k == i-1)    d_A[id + k] = 2.0; 
        if(k == i)      d_A[id + k] = 8.0;
        if(k == i+1)    d_A[id + k] = 2.0;
        if(k == i+2)    d_A[id + k] = 1.0;  
        } 
     d_B[idb] = 8.0;   
    }


int main()
 {
    cublasHandle_t handle;      cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&handle));

// Allocate device space for the input matrices
  double *d_A_sys; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A_sys, N*N*Nmatrices*sizeof(double));
  double *d_B_sys; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_B_sys, N*Nmatrices  *sizeof(double));

// Allocate host space for the solution
  double *h_B_sys = (double *)malloc(N*Nmatrices*sizeof(double));

// kernel for initiat d_A_sys and d_B_sys
  initiate<<<Nmatrices, N>>>(d_A_sys, d_B_sys);

//Creating the array of pointers needed as input/output to the batched getrf
  double **h_A_pointers = (double **)malloc(Nmatrices*sizeof(double *));
  for (int i = 0; i < Nmatrices; i++) h_A_pointers[i] = d_A_sys + i*N*N;

  double **h_b_pointers = (double **)malloc(Nmatrices*sizeof(double *));
  for (int i = 0; i < Nmatrices; i++) h_B_pointers[i] = d_B_sys + i*N;

  double **d_A_pointers;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A_pointers, Nmatrices*sizeof(double *));
  cudaMemcpy(d_A_pointers, h_A_pointers, Nmatrices*sizeof(double *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


  double **d_b_pointers;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b_pointers, Nmatrices*sizeof(double *));
  cudaMemcpy(d_b_pointers, h_b_pointers, Nmatrices*sizeof(double *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  int *d_InfoArrays; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_InfoArrays,  Nmatrices*sizeof(int));
  int *h_InfoArrays = (int *)malloc(Nmatrices*sizeof(int));

//Batched LU decomposition
   cublasDgetrfBatched(handle, N, d_A_pointers, N, NULL, d_InfoArrays, Nmatrices));

  //Batched Lower triangular part
  cublasDtrsmBatched(handle, 
                   CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, 
                   CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER,
                   CUBLAS_OP_N,
                   CUBLAS_DIAG_UNIT,
                   N,
                   N,
                   &alpha,
                   d_A_pointers,
                   N,
                   d_b_pointers,
                   N,
                   Nmatrices);

  //Batched Upper triangular part
  cublasDtrsmBatched(handle,
                   CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT,
                   CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER,
                   CUBLAS_OP_N,
                   CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT,
                   N,
                   N,
                   &alpha,
                   d_A_pointers,
                   N,
                   d_b_pointers,
                   N,
                   Nmatrices);

  cudaMemcpy(h_B_sys, d_B_sys, N*Nmatrices*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("Print out the solutions \n");

  cublasDestroy(handle);
  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
  return 0;
 }
```

[cublasDgetrfBatched](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-getrfbatched) and [cublasDtrsmBatched](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-trsmbatch) demand *d_A_pointers* should be in **double** type but when I execute, the later one giving me compiling error like this [see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3hHO.png):

How to overcome the problem, any help?

Comment: double versus const double is completely irrelevant in this case

Comment: Thanks @talonmies for your interest. May you tell me what is the problem with approach 1?

Comment: I cannot because you have not provided an [MCVE] (in either of your recent questions, which are likely stemming from the same un-diagnosed problem in code you have not shown)

Comment: I apologies @talonmies. I am new. Now if you could help.

Comment: please edit your question to include a [mcve]  On SO, when you ask a question of the form "why isn't this code working?" you are *required* to provide a [mcve].  Please read item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the const correctness issue by doing something like this:

```
const double **d_A_pointers;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A_pointers, Nmatrices*sizeof(double *));

....

//Batched LU decomposition
cublasDgetrfBatched(handle, N, const_cast<double**>(d_A_pointers), N, NULL, d_InfoArrays, Nmatrices);
```

i.e. cast away the constness  in the `cublasDgetrfBatched`

The other thing you obviously have wrong in the posted code is the dimensions of the inputs in the  `cublasDtrsmBatched` calls. I believe you want something like:

```
//Batched Lower triangular part
cublasDtrsmBatched(handle, 
        CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, 
        CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER,
        CUBLAS_OP_N,
        CUBLAS_DIAG_UNIT,
        N,
        1,
        &alpha,
        d_A_pointers,
        N,
        d_b_pointers,
        N,
        Nmatrices);
```

i.e. the input size of the RHS matrix for your example is Nx1, not NxN (you are not solving N RHS problems per factorised matrix, only one).

There are possibly other problems in your code (note that CUBLAS, like most reference BLAS implementations requires inputs in column major ordering by default), and the code you posted in your question doesn't actually compile for other reasons, so it is impossible to say more for sure.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer so that the question falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag